# Why can't Rayleigh Flow admit total temperature ratios higher than 1?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, flow

In a constant area duct inviscid flow where heat is added, there are some well established results in the literature known as Rayleigh flow (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_flow). In this scenario the initial state (state 1) can be know (ie Mach number, Static Temperature and thus Total Temperature as well)  and we can obtain the Total Temperature ratio as a function of Mach number.  The typical procedure to solve such a problem is given bellow.

Following this methodology if $T_{01} , M_1, q$  is know then we can obtain T02 from the 1st relationship. This means that $T_{02}$ is controlled by the heat addition thus $T_{02}$ can be any arbitrary number depending on the heat we add.The next steps (2 and 3) involve finding $T_{01}/T_{0*}$ and $T_{02}/T_{0*}$. This can lead to a value of $T_{02}$ that is bigger than one. In step 4 the right hand side of the equation can be shown to always be less than 1. As a result when we try to compute M2 from step 4 we cannot obtain a solution to this equation if $T_{02}/T_{0*}$ is bigger than one. What is the meaning of this in the context of our theoretical analysis? I am interested in the **theoretical** understanding of why we cannot obtain a solution using these equations.

[image: Rayleigh Flow Problem Solving]

[image: Rayleigh Flow Schematic]